# Read from multiple inputstream with one blocking call

Tags: java, inputstream, selector, bufferedreader

I have multiple `InputStream`, and I want to read without polling. My actual code:

```
BufferedReader p = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(k.getInputStream())); 
BufferedReader p2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(k2.getInputStream()));

String s = null;

while(true){

    if (p.ready()) {
        s = p.readLine();
        System.out.println("[+] "+s);
    }

    if (p2.ready()) {
        s = p2.readLine();
        System.out.println("[+] "+s);
    }

    sleep(1000);
}
```

Is there a way to read from them with one blocking call as:

```
select(p,p2); //blocking call returning the first inputstream has data to read
```

`SequenceInputStream` blocks sequentially on a chain of `InputStream` so it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will need multithreading in order to achieve that. You may use `CompletableFuture` as one of the means of doing it.

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // blocking read from p1
    return "Result from future 1";
});

CompletableFuture<String> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // blocking read from p2
    return "Result from future 2";
});

CompletableFuture<Object> resultFuture = CompletableFuture.anyOf(future1, future2);
```

Comment: Mh ok, but isn't this a waste of resources? Imagine having 100 InputStream, CompletableFuture will create 100 thread to do that right? @LevanGoderdzishvili

Comment: It will. But you want to attempt something like running multiple methods in parallel with random Thread.sleep(randomTime) and trying to figure out which one wakes up first. I don't see another way of doing it unless the BufferedReader would provide something out of the box, which doesn't seem it does.

If resources are a big deal, you may try enhancing it with executor pools or smth.

Comment: Thank you! I read of Selector but it doesn't seem to be usable for generic InputStream , isnt' it? @Levan Goderdzishvili

Comment: Right, @SempriGno, you won't be able to use it for generic InputSteams

Answer (score 0):

You can create a publisher class by two `BufferedReader`, which will publish a `String` when ready.

Then register with the publisher to get the next `String`.

Here is the sample code without testing.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //... Generating p and p2.
        
        InputStreams iss = new InputStreams(p, p2);
        iss.addNextStringListener(s -> {
            System.out.println("[+]" + s);
        });
        iss.start();
    }

    static class InputStreams{
        BufferedReader p;
        BufferedReader p2;

        public InputStreams(BufferedReader p, BufferedReader p2) {
            this.p = p;
            this.p2 = p2;
        }

        List<Consumer<String>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

        void start(){
            start(p);
            start(p2);
        }

        void start(BufferedReader br){
            new Thread(() -> {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        if (!br.ready()) break;
                        notifyNextString(br.readLine());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        void addNextStringListener(Consumer<String> listener){
            listeners.add(listener);
        }

        void notifyNextString(String nextString){
            listeners.forEach(l -> l.accept(nextString));
        }
    }
```